# The complexity of n choose 2 is in Theta (n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, big-o

I'm reading [Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition (Cormen and Rivest)](http://en.tjcities.com/wp-content/uploads/Books/Algorithms_3rd.pdf) and on page 69 in the "A brute-force solution" they state that n choose 2 = Theta (n^2). I would think it would be in Theta (n!) instead. Why is n choose 2 tightly bound to n squared? Thanks!

Comment: n choose 2 = n(n+1)/2 = (n^2 + n)/2...

Comment: @DennisMeng- It's n(n-1)/2 rather than n(n+1)/2.

Comment: Of course! I for some reason was thinking that n choose k was (n!)/(k!).

Comment: You can use the wonderful Wolfram Alpha website to get a clue: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=approximate+%7Bn+choose+2%7D+at+n+-%3E+infinity

Answer (score 33, accepted):

n choose 2 is

> n(n - 1) / 2

This is

> n<sup>2</sup> / 2 - n/2

We can see that n(n-1)/2 = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) by taking the limit of their ratios as n goes to infinity:

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (n<sup>2</sup> / 2 - n / 2) / n<sup>2</sup> = 1/2

Since this comes out to a finite, nonzero quantity, we have n(n-1)/2 = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

More generally: n choose k for any fixed constant k is Θ(n<sup>k</sup>), because it's equal to

> n! / (k!(n - k)!) = n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1) / k!

Which is a kth-degree polynomial in n with a nonzero leading coefficient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course! I for some reason was thinking that n choose k was (n!)/(k!).

Comment: @JennyShoars- That would definitely be confusing.  Hope this cleared things up!

Comment: wont this be `n^2/2 - n^2/2`? Thank you.

Comment: Your last claim is only true up to `k = n / 2`, at which point the `k` and `n - k` in the denominator of the choose function flip dominance in the cancellation and the complexity starts decreasing again, eventually reducing to `n choose n == 1`.  The correct generalization is that it's a `theta(min(k, n-k))` order polynomial.

Comment: @pjs Great point. I think this depends on what we think is variable and what we think is fixed. If k is a fixed constant and n is a variable, then for sufficiently large values of n we'll have n > k/2 as needed. (We could formalize this by finding proper values of c and n_0 to make this work.)

Comment: Okay, that's a good way to think of it since in reality O() is a description of scaling rather than a prediction of work.  If we view `n` as the parameter being scaled at some point it will overtake `k` for any fixed `k`, in which case your statement holds as-is.