# Explain how nC2 is Θ(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, clrs

In the book CLRS, in page 69 it's said nC2 is Θ(n^2) in the unit divide and conquer(U - 4). Can anyone expalin how this result is true?

Comment: < CONSTn^2 for all n>0, CONST=1/2 - which means O(n^2) by definition

Comment: You can see it that way: you choose your first element (O(n) choices possible) then your second (O(n) again) so you have a O(n²) upper bound.

Comment: @amit-he is asking about theta notation!

Comment: @user189-he is asking about theta notation!

Comment: @shekharsuman It will be pretty much identical to show the same thing for big Omega, and from there it is big theta by definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The complexity of n choose 2 is in Theta (n^2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415988/the-complexity-of-n-choose-2-is-in-theta-n2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> nC2 = n*(n-1)/2 = (n^2-n)/2;

**Hint :**

`(n^2-n)/2` will be greater than `c1*(n^2)` for some constants like `c1 < 1/4` and for value of `n = 2`. Similarly it will be smaller than `c2*n^2` for values of `c2 = 1` and `n = 2`. So, here is it's a sandwich like situation. Similarly, it'll be sandwiched for other values of n and constants c. Hence, `nC2 is Θ(n^2)`.